# Ajax postback does not change MVC dropdownlistfor selected value

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am using ASP.NET MVC 5 and i encountered a problem where the dropdownlist selected value does not change when i post back using ajax, null selected value is being passed for Model.SelectedItem. Unlike the case for Html.DropDownListFor, Html.EditorFor do passed the value in text input to Model.ItemA and Model.ItemB.

Note:
I have inspect the given html, and it appears that the first option value is being selected by defualt, but still the Model.SelectedItem is null on ajax call. When the ajax is called, the dropdownlist display remains as the option we selected beforehand, but still the selected option inspect by html shows as the first option and Model.SelectedItem remains null.

The dropdownlistfor implementation works perfectly fine if full postback is done on the page, but not a case where ajax is called partially.

hopefully i have clearly described the problem that i encountered. Below is the code that i did.

```js
$('#SelectedItem').change(function(){
  var itemA = $('#ItemA').val();
  var itemB = $('#ItemB').val();
  var selectedItem = $('#SelectedItem:selected').val();
  
  $.ajax({
    url: '@Url.Action("Index", "Home")',
    type: "POST",
    data: { param1 = itemA, param2 = itemB, param3 = selectedItem },
    success: function(){
      $('#ajaxDisplay').html('...');
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<div id = "Container">
  @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ItemA);
  @Html.EditorFor(model => model.itemB);
  @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SelectedItem, new SelectList(Model.Item, "Value", Text"), new {@class= ""})
  <div id = "ajaxDisplay">

  </div>
</div>

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(string param1, string param2, int? param3)
{
   return View();
}
```

Comment: What is `model` in `data: { param1 = model.ItemA, param2 = model.ItemB, param3 = model.SelectedItem },`? Your not getting the current value of your controls - i.e. `var selectedItem = $('#SelectedItem').val();`

Comment: oh yup, I have mistakenly type the code here. it should be var itemA = $('ItemA').val(); var itemB = $('ItemB').val();  var selectedItem = $('#SelectedItem:selected').val();      data: {param1 = itemA, param2 = itemB, param3 = selectedItem. The situation is still the same as i have mentioned above, null value is returned for selectedItem where the html for selected is always remain the first in the list of options.

Comment: Then edit your question with the correct code. And include the signature for the method your posting to (is it really `ActionResult Index(string param1, string param2, string param3)`?

Comment: it was int? should it be string?

Comment: No, it can be `int?` What you have shown should work fine. But since your binding to a model, why not just serialize the form and bind back to your model?

Comment: thanks stephen on the form serialising. I just got to know about this. However, i did not think the problem is with form serialising. As a matter of fact, var selectedItem = $('#SelectedItem:selected').val(); alert(selectedItem); pop up alert box with no content. However, I will give it a try and give feedback later.

Comment: Try `$('#SelectedItem').val();` or just `$(this).val();`. If that's not working then there is some other issue because there should be no difference between what you doing with this code and a normal submit which you claim is working. Also try `var data = $('form').serialize()` and inspect the values

Comment: Also it should be `data: { param1: itemA, param2: itemB, param3: selectedItem },`

Comment: big thanks, $('#SelectedItem').val(); solved the problem

Comment: Side note: Next time you comment, click on the help link :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

var itemA = $('ItemA').val(); instead of var itemA = $('ItemA:selected').val();

as mentioned by Stephen Muecke